# Does ArcMap have non-breaking space for labels?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, labeling

Is it possible to have a non-breaking space in ArcMap? I particularly need it for labels.

```
&amp; gives me a & but
&nbsp; doesn't work.
```

Is there any way to make a non-breaking space?

I'm using Arc10, but this question applies to previous versions as well.

Comment: It this the same question as: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1811/how-to-prevent-label-from-automatically-creating-a-new-line-when-applying-labels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, I don't know of one, and can't find one; doesn't mean it doesn't exist, but the help does indicate that there's only two "special" characters considered, which are replacements for the "&" and "<" characters.
[This help page](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=About_building_label_expressions) has info on all the special bits you can do for a label, but I don't see anything for the equivalent of non-breaking space.

The Maplex labeling engine has a whole bunch of other rules though, including the maximum number of lines it's allowed to use, and what characters to break a line on. While this isn't *exactly* what you're asking, it might suffice, assuming you can use maplex. See [the stacking docs](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/About_stacking_labels/003s0000002w000000/) for further info.

And yes, this seems to be a nigh-duplicate of [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1811/how-to-prevent-label-from-automatically-creating-a-new-line-when-applying-labels). I've got to remember to start looking before answering.

Answer (score 0):

`&" "&` should work in the label query for normal and maplex labelling engines.

It is also possible to convert to Graphical Annotation if only a few.